# Comma use when omitting a repeated verb (ellipsis)

Tags: commas, ellipses

I am 'querying' an agent...  And I would like to keep grammar mistakes and infelicities down to a manageable dozen. So here goes:

In the following sentence,

```
   "In the story, Gilgamesh is king, and Enkidu lowly beast."
```

is the second comma necessary? According to the internet, it seems so, and I tend to agree. On the other hand, I would also have been tempted to write,

```
   "In the story, Gilgamesh is king, and Enkidu, lowly beast."
```

Is this incorrect? If not, is one form preferable over the other?

Thank you in advance.

(Note: the above sentence does not appear in the 'query' letter, but one with that structure does.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, this is an elliptical clause, the 'full' version being: "In the story, Gilgamesh is king, and Enkidu **is** a lowly beast.

For the sake of completeness, I'll give this definition from [Dailywritingtips](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/a-guide-to-elliptical-constructions/):

> An elliptical construction is one in which a word or phrase implied by
>   context is omitted from a sentence, usually because it is a repetition
>   of a preceding word or phrase.

Your first sentence -- "In the story, Gilgamesh is king, and Enkidu lowly beast" -- is fine, and is corroborated by Dailywritingtips example of verb ellipses.

> Verb ellipsis: “She favors romantic comedies, and Jane [favors]
>   musicals.”

Your second suggestion isn't good grammatically. It looks like parenthesis, which it isn't. On the other hand it would work if, instead of the first comma, you used a semi-colon:

> In the story, Gilgamesh is king; (and) Enkidu, lowly beast.

Here's an example from [Grammar.com](https://www.grammar.com/commas-and-elliptical-expressions/)

> In Illinois, there are seventeen such institutions; in Ohio,
>   twenty-two; in Indiana, three.

However, the above example needs the semicolon to clearly keep Ohio's data away from Indiana's. In your example, it's not really necessary. My stylistic preference would be your first sentence.

Comment: (+1) and thank you for the links and your answer. I suppose my temptation to add the extra comma is reflected in your semi-colon option. When I read the sentence out loud ( '[...] king, and Enkidu lowly beast'), I hear a pause after Enkidu.